# Canvas to data url not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>

    <script>
    function mypng(){ 
    var c=document.getElementById("picture");
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    alert(dataURL);
    }
    </script>


    <a id="jpeg" href="#" onclick="mypng();">

  <canvas id="picture"></canvas>
```

but nothing happens, not run the function.

of course I am generating an image on the canvas. If I right click the image and select view this image I can see correctly and encoded in base64 url

Comment: whats error?? any error od what happens

Comment: What are html2canvas and canvas2image ?

Comment: the function is not executed, the alert with the url is never executed.

Comment: Just thinking... have you triedto add a `event.preventDefault()` inside the `mypng(event){` function?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: @metalbox you know HTML, right? You should close `<a>` tags

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan size string is to large https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m59b7q9dxzv8e1/url%20image%20base%2064.txt?dl=0

Comment: @metalbox 290 KB is not a large string. 6+MB would probably be.

Answer (score 0):

`<a id="jpeg" href="#" onclick="mypng();">`

It is a link, so return false on click event to prevent going to /#.

`<a id="jpeg" href="#" onclick="mypng(); return false;">`

EDIT:

Also, you do not close the `<a>` tag.

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="js/canvas2image.js"></script>

<script>
function mypng(){ 
    var c=document.getElementById("picture");
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    alert(dataURL);
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>


<a id="jpeg" href="#" onclick="mypng();">LINK</a>

<canvas id="picture"></canvas>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/09knjotm/1/)

Comment: he uses a function so better use a `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you. The less logic in HTML - the better.

Comment: @kurdeja exactly... though as I've already noticed in the OP's question comment section that it might be about events... I'm a bit suspicious that it's the real deal...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, with the given piece of code it is the only real flaw and a probable cause of the problem. It is not clear how the image is drawn on canvas. If it is taken from another server, some browsers do not allow converting canvas to dataURL. But CORS errors should be shown in the console log...

Comment: i use event.preventDefault() but is the same.

Comment: @metalbox show how you use it. (I'm saying it by experience. "I use it" usually means "I use it wrongly")

Comment: i take a snapshot from a videocamera and drawn into the canvas, after this I run the above function.

Comment: i use this 

function mypng(){ 
$("jpeg").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
 
  });

    var c=document.getElementById("picture");
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    alert(dataURL);
    }

Comment: I found the problem. Please look at my edited answer with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/09knjotm/)

Comment: I think the problem is the size of the string is too large.

Comment: @kurideja Here the image url base64 code https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m59b7q9dxzv8e1/url%20image%20base%2064.txt?dl=0

Comment: @metalbox, just console.log it then, do not alert it. It is definitely a huge data url.